# vba - export Access table to file named by user

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm currently exporting a table in Access 2013 to an Excel file using TransferSpreadsheet.  I set the default filename and location.  It's working fine, except that when the user changes the name they want to save the file as in the Save As dialog, the is not saved with that name.  Is there a way I can get the file name the user entered in the Save As dialog and save the file with that name in the location they select?

Here's what I'm doing now:

```
Dim strTableName As String
Dim strBasePath As String
Dim strFullPath As String
Dim strFileName As String
Dim dlgSaveAs As Object
Const msoFileDialogSaveAs = 2

With CodeContextObject
    strTableName = "New_Rules"
    strBasePath = "C:\Users\" & Environ("USERNAME") & "\Documents\"
    strFileName = "New_Account_Rules_" & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd")
    strFullPath = strBasePath & strFileName & ".xls"
    ' Display the Save As dialog with a default name and path
    Set dlgSaveAs = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
    With dlgSaveAs
        .InitialFileName = strFullPath
        If dlgSaveAs.Show Then
            ' Do the export
            DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "New_Rules", strFullPath, True
        End If
    End With
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The `SelectedItems()` collection contains the list of filenames entered/selected.   Since you're using the *msoFileDialogSaveAs* option, the `FileDialog` will permit only one selected item.  So when `.Show` is True, just assign `.SelectedItems(1)` to your `strFullPath` variable:

```
With dlgSaveAs

    ' Set the initial/default filename...
    .InitialFileName = strFullPath

    If .Show Then

        ' Get the selected/entered filename...
        strFullPath = .SelectedItems(1)

        ' Do the export...
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "New_Rules", strFullPath, True

    End If
End With
```

Comment: Great! Thanks! That worked. I knew there had to be an easy way to do that.